# How create this effect 3D with CSS3

Tags: css, transform, shapes

The effect I'm trying to make is as in this image:

> http://i271.photobucket.com/albums/jj146/cosmossx/footer.jpg

I've made some progress as you can see in this **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5nyr3jo6/light/)**

css:

```
  .final{ background:#000;
  width:100%;}
  .triangle {
    border-color: white black black black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 25px 25px 25px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.triangle2 {
    border-color: black white white white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 25px 25px 25px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="final">  <div class="triangle"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>

</div>
<div class="triangle2"></div>
```

My question is: what would be the best way to make it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach would be using css `transform` function and pseudo-elements

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/ogJMOJ?editors=110)**

Source (using Sass and Autoprefixer for brevity):

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer__main">
          <div class="footer__inner">
               <div class="footer__content">
                  <!-- content goes here -->
               </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer__bottom"></div>
</footer>
```

```
.footer {
    height: 500px;
}

.footer__main {
    height: 80%;
    background: #eee;
}

.footer__bottom {
    height: 20%;
    background: darken(#eee, 20);
}

.footer__inner {
    background: white;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.footer__content {
    background: #eee;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateY(20px);
    position: relative;
    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: "";
        background: darken(#eee, 10);
        width: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; bottom: 0;
        z-index: 2;
   }
   &:before {
        right: 100%;
        transform-origin: 100%;
        transform: skewY(45deg);
    }
    &:after {
        transform-origin: 0;
        left: 100%;
        transform: skewY(-45deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but my reputation is Low

Comment: Oh yeah, you can't upvote yet. I forgot about that. But you can still accept answer as question author.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
A big thank you for your Support